# How to use file-oriented functions in PHP without writing on block device?

Tags: php

There are some functions using files.
First function generating some content and might write it to file or any other output.
Second function can't be re-written because is binding to GTK\C function.

It accepts filename as parameter.

```php
<?php
...
file_put_contents("/dev/shm/icon.png",$PNG);

$img = GtkImage::new_from_file("/dev/shm/icon.png");
```

So my question: **is there a way to bypass writing\reading using block device?**
I read about php://memory and php://temp but as I understand they allows to read immediately after writing before descriptor is closed.

Thanks.

Comment: What is a "block device" in your own words?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean, or what problem you're trying to solve. See also [ask]

Comment: Is your usage of "block" related to "lock" and/or exclusive access?

Comment: You might be able to use https://github.com/bovigo/vfsStream or register your own handler via [stream_wrapper_register](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php).

Comment: No. If a builtin function takes a filename, then you're not getting around it without rewriting the function yourself, which may or may not be feasible. If you just want to avoid writing to a slow disk then you can set up a [tmpfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/tmpfs.html) at the OS level and write it to that temporarily.

Comment: @Sammitch _"If a builtin function takes a filename, then you're not getting around it without rewriting the function yourself"_ - it _might_ be possible, if the content was converted into a Data URI, I would think? https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php allows only reading, no writing - but that should be enough here for this particular use case. `allow_url_fopen` would have to be activated. This might not be an option for files above a certain size, but `icon.png` suggests that those images might not be that big to begin with.